# How to set up the Team Foundation Server repository in vs code?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm using `visual studio code version 1.26.1` for angular projects.

Right now I'm using source control GIT. But I would like to change this to Team Foundation Server.

So that I have installed the Visual Studio Team Services. Once after that, I have done the following things:

1. `Open File -> Preferences -> Settings`
2. Add the following lines to your user settings

   ```
   {
     "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe",
   "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
   ```

   }
3. Open a local folder (repository), `From View -> Command Pallette` ..., type `team signin`

When I select the sign in from command palette I got the following error

```
(team) No Team Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.
```

How to set up the Team Foundation Server repository. Do I need to uninstall the `GIT` for use the `TFS`?

Comment: Is the local repository you opened a TFVC workspace? Or it is a Git repository?

Comment: I opened git repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a folder containing a Local TFVC Workspace. Refer to this link for details: [Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) Support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start).

It supports workspaces created with Visual Studio (via tf.exe) or the JetBrains IDEs and Eclipse (via the Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client)

Comment: I have referred the link and followed the setup but when I open the "Add folder to workspace" I got this error "You are running the system-wide installation of Code, while having the user-wide distribution installed as well. Make sure you're running the Code version you expect."

Comment: @Kumar19 This is a warning about the VS Code version. Did it block you?

Comment: It did not block me. I got a little confused since I'm new to visual studio code I don't know how TFS will work in visual studio code. I just add a text file in visual studio online portal I did a sync. But the file got stored in my local folder C:\Users\Anu\.vscode\Angular\New Text Document.txt but I my workspace is in D:\My_Space\Angular. Why the file downloaded in  D:\My_Space\Angular folder instead of C:\Users\Anu\.vscode\Angular\. How to change this? And could you please share any step by step document for integrating TFS with vs code?

Comment: There is a vedio in the link I share: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be  It containds detailed steps.

Comment: I've same question. In that video, he opens one that was previously open. How does one open one the first time? If I navigate to my local folder, the "open" command does nothing.

Comment: I found one solution path following these steps:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-azure-data-studio-with-tfvc