# Error (No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure) When sharing a project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I want to share my project in VSCode 2019, for this I have installed Azure Repos, then in (Command Pallette) I executed the team signin command, but I was faced with the following warning, how to fix my problem And share it with my work environment.

`No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.`

[image]

Comment: Hello @Ali - Please take a look at this to see if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938308/how-to-set-up-the-team-foundation-server-repository-in-vs-code

Comment: In step 2, add the words, where should I add them? I entered the settings, but I do not know where to add them.

Comment: @Ali How is your problem progressing? Is the following answer helpful to you?If yes ,could you [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread.If not ,you can raise your doubts. Let's investigate further.Thanks.

Comment: I have solved the problem that was raised here now, then if there is a problem, I will definitely share it with the team.
Thankful

Comment: I have defined my project in DevOps but I get the following warning in vsCode:`Unable to find the TF executable. Please ensure TF is installed and the path specified contains the filename.`

Comment: tfvc location: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe", “tfvc.restrictWorkspace”: true`

Answer (score 2):

> In step 2, add the words, where should I add them? I entered the
> settings, but I do not know where to add them

Open VsCode -> File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Search `tfvc` inside the "Search settings" input -> Add the full path to that `Tfvc:Location` option

[image]

> No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository
> configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a
> repository

For creating the repository, we need Visual Studio IDE, Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ). or any sort of IDE for sure. Without that, we cannot start using the TFVC with VSCode.

You can follow the steps in this [blog](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedures-to-integrate-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-with-visual-studio-code-vscode-for-sharepoint-framework-spfx-projects/) with a detailed guide.

In addition, you can refer to official [document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#configure-tfvc-support) for details.